# List event handler in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm

The CRM 201X SDK provides methods to add and remove event handlers on many events like form load, field on change etc.

**My question is**: Is it possible to get a list of all events registered at runtime?

Let's say I want to remove all `onSave` handlers from a form (but I don't have a pointer to them as they may originated from other scripts). Can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible by poking around in the debugger (presumably it is stored in some property, but there is not a supported `Xrm.Page` function to retrieve this information.

Comment: I think you can do that, but it will only remove the events attached by an addOnSave. You can't know the functions added.

Comment: @Sxntk: But how do I remove the events I'm not the one who added it? I don't have a function pointer to pass to the remove method